# Using multiple different editors on the same page “CKEDITOR5”

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor, ckeditor5

Using multiple different editors on the same page “**CKEDITOR5**”
Classic e Balloon

I can't put two different types of editors on one page.
Below I leave an example of what it would be like to place 2 different editors.

But as I have a library for each type of editor it appears to say  “**CKEditorError: ckeditor-duplicated-modules: Some CKEditor 5 modules are duplicated.**”

And sorry for the bad English.

```
<div class="editorclassic">
</div>
<div class="editorballoon">
</div>

// The two libraries repeated but each adapted to a type of editor
<script src="plugins/ckeditor5classic/build/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script src="plugins/ckeditor5ballon/build/ckeditor.js"></script>

// Initialize both types of editors
<script>
            ClassicEditor
            .create( document.querySelector( '.editornormal' ), {
                toolbar: {
                    items: [
                        'heading',
                        '|',
                        'bold',
                        'italic',
                        'bulletedList',
                        'numberedList',
                        '|',
                        '|',
                        'imageUpload',
                        'blockQuote',
                        'insertTable',
                        'mediaEmbed',
                        'undo',
                        'redo'
                    ]
                },
                language: 'pt',
                licenseKey: '',

            } )
            .then( editor => {
                window.editor = editor;
            } )
            .catch( error => {
                console.error( error );
            } );



            BalloonEditor
            .create( document.querySelector( '.editorballon' ), {
                toolbar: {
                    items: [
                        'heading',
                        '|',
                        'bold',
                        'italic',
                        'link',
                        'bulletedList',
                        'numberedList',
                        '|',
                        'indent',
                        'outdent',
                        '|',
                        'imageUpload',
                        'blockQuote',
                        'insertTable',
                        'mediaEmbed',
                        'undo',
                        'redo'
                    ]
                },
                language: 'pt',
                image: {
                    toolbar: [
                        'imageTextAlternative',
                        'imageStyle:full',
                        'imageStyle:side'
                    ]
                },
                table: {
                    contentToolbar: [
                        'tableColumn',
                        'tableRow',
                        'mergeTableCells'
                    ]
                },
                licenseKey: '',

            } )
            .then( editor => {
                window.editor = editor;
            } )
            .catch( error => {
                console.error( error );
            } );
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
var numb = 1;
  do {
    ClassicEditor
    .create( document.querySelector( '#body'+ numb ), {
      removePlugins: [ 'insertImage', 'insertMedia', 'Link', 'blockQuote' ],
      toolbar: [ 'Heading', 'bold', 'italic', 'bulletedList', 'numberedList',  ]
    } ) 
    .catch( error => {
      console.error( error );
    } )
    numb++;
  }
  while (numb < 4);
});
```

```css
.ck-editor__editable_inline {
    min-height: 150px;  
  }
```

```html
<p><textarea  placeholder="Description"  id="body1" name="body"></textarea></p>
<p><textarea  placeholder="Description"  id="body2" name="body"></textarea></p>
<p><textarea  placeholder="Description"  id="body3" name="body"></textarea></p>

<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/18.0.0/classic/ckeditor.js"></script>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Excellent use of a code snippet, but almost all code only answers can be improved by adding some explanation of how and why they work. Doing so would also allow you to address the portion of the question where each of the two editors had slightly different configurations.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same question from a customer. More than one BalloonEditor on 1 page.
One solution would be to initialize every instance by his own id, but I thought that it would be easier to add one class to the elements I wanted to become an ballooneditor. So that's what I did:

I introduced a class `.editable` on selected elements:

```
<div id="elm1" class='editable'>
  Some text...
</div>

<div id="elm2" class='editable'>
  Some other text...
</div>
```

And then (in for instance the document ready function), I handled them as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var id;
  $('.editable').each(function() {
      id = $(this).attr('id');
      if (id != '') {
          BalloonEditor
              .create(document.querySelector( '#' + id ))
              .catch( error => {
                  console.error( 'error' );
              } )
      }
  })

  ....
  ..

});
```

To track changes to the different elements, I added a handler like this:

```
$('.editable').on('blur', function(ev) {
    console.log('en blurred');
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    console.log($(this).html())
    console.log(id);
})
```

That gave me the opportunity to save the changes with an AJAX handler.

It is just a suggestion, but it works fine for me.